# Swift 2.0 replicate OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime, swift2

I'm extending some classes in Swift 2.0 to work with ReactiveCocoa 3.0 (swift-2.0 branch), but have run into some trouble.

I've followed Colin [Eberhardt's tutorial](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/05/15/mvvm-reactive-cocoa-3.html), and have copy pasted some of his [UIKit extension logic](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/ReactiveTwitterSearch/blob/master/ReactiveTwitterSearch/Util/UIKitExtensions.swift) over to my OS X app. It all compiles fine, apart from this property: `UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)`, which gives me the following compiler error.

> use of unresolved identifier

How can I access this property? I've tried to `import ObjectiveC` and `#import <objc/runtime.h>` in the header file, but nothing seems to work.

```
func lazyAssociatedProperty<T: AnyObject>(host: AnyObject, key: UnsafePointer<Void>, factory: ()->T) -> T {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(host, key) as? T ?? {
        let associatedProperty = factory()

        objc_setAssociatedObject(host, key, associatedProperty, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)) // <-- Use of unresolved identifier
        return associatedProperty
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually now imported into Swift as an enum named `objc_AssociationPolicy`. Definition:

```
enum objc_AssociationPolicy : UInt {
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN        
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY
}
```

Meaning that it can be used as follows.

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(host, key, associatedProperty, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
```

Or with enum shorthand syntax.

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(host, key, associatedProperty, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
```

Note that `objc_setAssociatedObject` has also been updated to take a `objc_AssociationPolicy` argument instead of `UInt` making it unnecessary to access the enum's `rawValue` here.