# Swift 2 : OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, swift2

I just updated my project to Swift 2.

I one of my swift class I use ObjC association.

I have the following :

```
objc_AssociationPolicy( OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
```

Since the update, the compiler returns `Use of unresolved identifier 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC'`.

Any idea why ?

---

Edit: 
For those who have the same problem, a temporary fix would be to replace the constant with its value ie. 1 : `objc_AssociationPolicy( rawValue: 1 )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2.0 replicate OBJC\_ASSOCIATION\_RETAIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872626/swift-2-0-replicate-objc-association-retain)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you look at the obj c runtime swift header, it appears this construct has become an enum:

```
/**
 * Policies related to associative references.
 * These are options to objc_setAssociatedObject()
 */
enum objc_AssociationPolicy : UInt {

    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN
    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC

    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC

    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN

    case OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY
}
```

So you can replace with: `objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`.

If you need the token as a UInt, you can always use .rawValue.

(In the previous version `objc_AssociationPolicy` was just a typealias for UInt - with the effect of casting 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC', an Int)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import ObjectiveC.runtime

func setOverlay(view: UIView)
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.overlayKey, view, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}
```